# BitmapFactory.decodeStream issues

Tags: android, android-animation, bitmapfactory

I am creating an application with frame by frame animation using almost 150 image frames.  The animation is played by changing the background image of an Image view using Handler. Inside the handler I am retrieving the images from the folder /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/ApplicationPackage and changing it dynamically as the image view background by the following way :

```
FileInputStream in;                       
in = new FileInputStream(mFrames.get(imgpos));                              
bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in); 
if (in != null)
{   
    in.close();
}
```

This creates some issues in decoding the file input stream since it takes a lot of time for some images to create the bitmap. Image file size is almost less than 40 KB for each images, but it takes different duration to decode the images from the external directory for the same size files.  I have tried to sample the file size and load but it directly affects the image clarity.  Can any one please suggest me what is the better way to load the images to a bitmap from the external folder and with the same duration for all the images?

Thanks, Tim

Comment: Since the images aren't very big in size compressed, maybe you could preload them as byte arrays into memory for decoding?

Comment: You can create a Hashmap<String, Bitmap> and save decoded bitmap into hashmap and then start animation. This is not a good way but this will improve performance of animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must preload the bitmap before displaying them... Use an array of bitmap, and a background task that load all the images when entering your activity.
Your handler is absolutely not allowed to perform time-consuming tasks such as loading bitmaps !

Comment: Thanks but I tried to load the images in an ArrayList<Bitmap> before the thread starts, and caused the VM Exceeds exception straight away.

Comment: Well, this means that your bitmap total size may be too high for the device memory. Try this fix http://apachejava.blogspot.be/2011/02/bitmap-exceeds-vm-budget-solution.html. What are the exact size (in pixels) of the bitmaps ?

Comment: Image size almost comes about 35 - 40 KB for each frames and the images are of Dimensions 480 x 800

Comment: :O :O This is HUGE ! Did you realize that it's an equivalent of 164Mo of raw data ? (assuming you have RGB8 images) You 35-40ko size is not relevant, as it is the size of the (compressed) files...

Comment: its around 6.8 MB of total size for the images on the disc.

Comment: @Timson Thats a lot of memory for a bitmap. I had the same problem in my application. Then I scaled them according to the ImageView i was loading them in. Its much much faster now! Give a try to the code i posted.

Comment: yes, on the disk. But those files are compressed, and your app will have to load them uncompressed to use them. So, this is 480 x 800 x 150 x 3 bytes... Hey this is almost a 6 second-long HD movie !

Comment: Ok. So any suggestions for image optimization?

Comment: @Timson , have you tried preloading images as compressed byte arrays into memory for decoding (instead of FileInputStream)? 6.8MB of preloaded data shouldn't be too much of a trouble if your application doesn't consume too big chunks of memory elsewhere and sped up the decoding a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can downscale the images before creating the bitmap for them.

```
public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(String path) 
{
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, requiredWidth, requiredHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap newBmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    return newBmap;
}

public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) 
{
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (imageHeight > reqHeight || imageWidth > reqWidth) 
    {
        if (imageWidth > imageHeight) 
        {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)imageHeight / (float)reqHeight);
        } 
        else 
        {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)imageWidth / (float)reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

If the images are a lot bigger than the view in which they are loaded, then this down scaling really helps create the bitmap faster. Also, the scaled `Bitmap` takes much less memory than directly creating the bitmap.
`inJustDecodeBounds` in `BitmapFactory.Options` when set to `true` lets you get the height and width before creating the `Bitmap` for it. So you can check if the images are larger than required. If yes, then scale them to the required height and width, and then create its `Bitmap`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're welcome! The path that I pass to the `decodeSampledBitmapFromPath()` function is of the image I store in sd-card. So you might want to modify that accordingly.

Comment: Also, this whole process is done using `AsyncTask` so the UI never hangs.

Comment: Image view size is 480 x 800 and the image size is also the same.  So always the Sample size will be 1 only.  It does not make any difference.  Also, my problem is exactly with the Decode stream. With Galaxy S, it takes around 30 to 450 MilliSeconds to load a single image where as in Galaxy S2 its always less than 20 MilliSeconds and Animations is smooth on it